# JDBC Source Connector Error: Transaction was aborted. It was wounded by a higher priority transaction due to conflict on keys in range

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-spanner

I am using JDBC source connector with the JDBC Driver for collecting data from Google Cloud Spanner to Kafka.
I am using "timestamp+incrementing" mode on a table. The primary key of the table includes 2 columns (order_item_id and order_id).
I used order_item_id for the incrementing column, and a column named "updated_time" for timestamp column.

When I started the connector, I got the following errors sometimes, but I still can get the data finally.

```
ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table="order_item", query='null', 
topicPrefix='test_', incrementingColumn='order_item_id', timestampColumns=[updated_time]}: {} 
(io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:404)
com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcSqlExceptionFactory$JdbcAbortedDueToConcurrentModificationException: 
The transaction was aborted and could not be retried due to a concurrent modification
...
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.AbortedDueToConcurrentModificationException: 
The transaction was aborted and could not be retried due to a concurrent modification
...
Suppressed: com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.AbstractBaseUnitOfWork$SpannerAsyncExecutionException: 
Execution failed for statement: 
SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE `order_item`.`updated_time` < @p1 AND ((`order_item`.`updated_time` = @p2 AND `order_item`.`order_item_id` > @p3) OR `order_item`.`updated_time` > @p4) ORDER BY `order_item`.`updated_time`,`order_item`.`order_item_id` ASC
...
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.AbortedException: ABORTED: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: 
ABORTED: Transaction was aborted. It was wounded by a higher priority transaction due to conflict on keys in range [[5587892845991837697,5587892845991837702], [5587892845991837697,5587892845991837702]), column adjust in table order_item.
retry_delay {
  nanos: 12974238
}
 - Statement: 'SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE `order_item`.`updated_time` < @p1 AND ((`order_item`.`updated_time` = @p2 AND `order_item`.`order_item_id` > @p3) OR `order_item`.`updated_time` > @p4) ORDER BY `order_item`.`updated_time`,`order_item`.`order_item_id` ASC'
...
```

I am wondering how does this error happen in my case. Btw, even with the error, the connector can still collect the data at the end. Can anyone help with it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how your entire pipeline is set up, but the error indicates that you are executing the query in a read/write transaction. Any read/write transaction on Cloud Spanner can be aborted by Cloud Spanner, and may result in the error that you are seeing.

If your pipeline is only **reading** from Cloud Spanner, the best thing to do is to set your JDBC connection in **read-only** and **autocommit** mode. You can do this directly in your JDBC connection URL by adding the `readonly=true` and `autocommit=true` properties to the URL.

Example:

`jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/databases/my-database;readonly=true;autocommit=true`

It could also be that the framework(s) that you are using is changing the JDBC connection after it has been opened. In that case you should have a look if you can change that in the framework(s). But changing the JDBC URL based on the above example may very well be enough in this case.

##### Background information:

If the JDBC connection is opened with autocommit turned off and the connection is in read/write mode, then a read/write transaction will be started automatically when a query is executed. All subsequent queries will also use the same read/write transaction, until `commit()` is called on the connection. This is the least efficient way to read large amounts of data on Cloud Spanner, and should therefore be avoided whenever possible. It will also cause aborted transactions, as the read operations will take locks on the data that it is reading.

Comment: Hi Knut, thank you so much for your detailed explanation, solution and the context. It helps a lot for understanding the content of Spanner read/write in the JDBC connector setting!!!